# How do I change the order of a filename on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, file, rename

I've got a folder with a number of files in the following format:

> Photo 31-12-2020, 00 08 09.jpg

i.e. `dd-mm-yyyy, hr min sec.jpg`

I would like to rename them all files to the following format:

> 2020-12-31 00.08.09.jpg

i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd hr.mm.sec.jpg`

The changes are: year and day moved around, comma removed, dots between hours, minutes and seconds.

However, there are a couple of hundred of files in the folder, so I would like to automate this with a bash script.

I have looked into running a bash script to do this, but I’m unfortunately not very comfortable with scripting and wasn’t successful.

Could anyone help me find an easy method to resolve my issue?

Comment: Which is it, Mac or Linux? The tooling differs.

Comment: P.S.: what have you tried? In terms of sample data ... please use a filename in which month and day are actually distinguishable, e.g. 2020-02-29 ...

Comment: Hi @rene ... asking for a "tool" takes this question into the realm of "not a programming question" ... it would also make a re-open more likely if you actually added the failed bash attempts to the question.

Comment: Assuming you're in the directory in which the photos are .... this **should** work. `for i in Photo*jpg; do echo mv -v "${i}" "$(echo $i|awk  'BEGIN{FS="[ ,.-]"}{printf "%s-%s-%s %s.%s.%s.jpg\n",$4,$3,$2,$6,$7,$8}')"; done` ... if the output looks sensible, trim out the first `echo` ..

Comment: thank you tink! your command did exactly what I wanted it to do. Sorry if my question wasn't that clear or conclusive from the start, but I'm very happy with your help!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that. Do you have any questions regarding what the command does?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the directory in which the photos are .... this should work.

```
for i in Photo*jpg
  do 
    echo mv -v "${i}" "$(echo $i|awk  'BEGIN{FS="[ ,.-]"}{printf "%s-%s-%s %s.%s.%s.jpg\n",$4,$3,$2,$6,$7,$8}')"
  done
```

... if the output looks sensible, trim out the first `echo` ..